# How can I make this js work on a button tag instead of anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a plugin I found called dropit.js

I'm trying to use it on a button tag but it won't work, only a tags.

```
/*
* Dropit v1.1.0
* http://dev7studios.com/dropit
*
* Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
* Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

;(function($) {

$.fn.dropit = function(method) {

    var methods = {

        init : function(options) {
            this.dropit.settings = $.extend({}, this.dropit.defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var $el = $(this),
                     el = this,
                     settings = $.fn.dropit.settings;

                // Hide initial submenus
                $el.addClass('dropit')
                .find('>'+ settings.triggerParentEl +':has('+ settings.submenuEl +')').addClass('dropit-trigger')
                .find(settings.submenuEl).addClass('dropit-submenu').hide();

                // Open on click
                $el.off(settings.action).on(settings.action, settings.triggerParentEl +':has('+ settings.submenuEl +') > '+ settings.triggerEl +'', function(){
                    // Close click menu's if clicked again
                    if(settings.action == 'click' && $(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).hasClass('dropit-open')){
                        settings.beforeHide.call(this);
                        $(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).removeClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).hide();
                        settings.afterHide.call(this);
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Hide open menus
                    settings.beforeHide.call(this);
                    $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
                    settings.afterHide.call(this);

                    // Open this menu
                    settings.beforeShow.call(this);
                    $(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).addClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).show();
                    settings.afterShow.call(this);

                    return false;
                });

                // Close if outside click
                $(document).on('click', function(){
                    settings.beforeHide.call(this);
                    $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
                    settings.afterHide.call(this);
                });

                // If hover
                if(settings.action == 'mouseenter'){
                    $el.on('mouseleave', '.dropit-open', function(){
                        settings.beforeHide.call(this);
                        $(this).removeClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).hide();
                        settings.afterHide.call(this);
                    });
                }

                settings.afterLoad.call(this);
            });
        }

    };

    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in dropit plugin!');
    }

};

$.fn.dropit.defaults = {
    action: 'click', // The open action for the trigger
    submenuEl: 'ul', // The submenu element
    triggerEl: 'a', // The trigger element
    triggerParentEl: 'li', // The trigger parent element
    afterLoad: function(){}, // Triggers when plugin has loaded
    beforeShow: function(){}, // Triggers before submenu is shown
    afterShow: function(){}, // Triggers after submenu is shown
    beforeHide: function(){}, // Triggers before submenu is hidden
    afterHide: function(){} // Triggers before submenu is hidden
};

$.fn.dropit.settings = {};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the trigger element to button.

```
 triggerEl: 'button'
```